Обработка строк в массиве
Суть моего вопроса в том, что после парсинга страницы и некоторой обработки у меня имеется массив строк, который выглядит примерно так (каждый переход на новую строку => другой элемент массива):
"prop1: foo1"
"prop2:"
"foo2"
"foo2"
"prop3: foo3"

И мне нужно сделать так, чтобы всё имело такой вид: "prop: foo". Задачу осложняет то, что мы не можем предугадать сколько строк нам нужно объединить для каждого свойства. Их может быть и 3, может и не быть вовсе.
И у меня в голове есть некая идея: если строка оканчивается на ':', то присоединяем к ней все последующие строки, но до тех пор пока не встретим строку, содержащую ':'.

Как я понимаю тут необходимо 2 вложенных цикла, где 1 - будем обходить массив до тех пор, пока не встретит строку, оканчивающуюся на ':', а 2 - который будет обходить все элементы после, но до тех пор, пока не наткнётся на строку с ':'?
И я правильно понимаю, что логичнее будет заменять ненужные нам элементы (уже конкатенированные) на string.Empty, чтобы в последствии легко отсеять их?

Просто в данный момент что-то толковое в голову не идёт

Такое впечатление, будто вы криво изначально спарсили и сейчас решаете созданные самому себе проблемы. Думаю стоит показать как вы парсили и что, тогда можно будет попробовать найти более адекватное решение.

EvgeniyZ, сайт откуда я паршу - это F95Zone (к примеру), а паршу обыкновенно (AngleSharp): нахожу элемент по классу "bbwrapper", отрезаю лишнее (типо лишних пробелов и табуляций), разделяю на подстроки (потому что каждая страница максимально вариативна и нужно все в один вид привести), чтобы привести к читаемому виду и потом пропсы распаршиваю по Regex, я бы и не спрашивал, но поле Overview часто слишком вариантно: два абзац может быть, может быть спойлер, может быть что угодно и из-за этого не работало на 100%

Не думаю, что подобным перебором вы сделаете адекватное решение, ибо зачастую таких шаблонов тем очень много и каждый волен их менять как ему захочется, придется очень много подстраивать и менять в ходе работы. А так, как я и сказал, вы всеж не с того начали, ибо там четкая HTML структура, которую вы просто игнорируете и берете все как текст. Тут правильней будет взять все b и у каждого взять следующий элемент дерева, если делать через XPath, то сырой набросок будет следующий: //div[@class='bbWrapper']/b/following-sibling::node()[following-sibling::b].

Также можно отталкиваться от br. В любом случае, вы парсите HTML как текст, что не есть хорошо. Ну и замечу, что у сайта есть API, не вся информация там конечно есть, но может если еще поискать, то может можно найти больше... А вообще, подобный "сухой" анализ текста скорей всего лучше делать через NER анализаторы, например, вот, ибо повторю, у этой темы шаблон такой, а у следующей будет скорей всего отличаться, и весь ваш парсер упадет...

@EvgeniyZ, благодарю вас за развёрнутый ответ:

насчёт некого API буду знать, просто он лежит не в таком явном виде, как я думал
про работу с текстом - это да, почему-то на начальном этапе мне показалось это разумным, но чем дальше в лес, тем хуже...
про NER занимательно, надо будет поразмыслить над этим...


Можно использовать List для добавления необходимых строк, и осуществлять поиск в массиве до следующего найденного знака ':' в очередной строке, после чего добавлять новую строку:
static string[] ParseString(string[] arr)
{
    List<string> result = new();
    foreach (var item in arr)
    {
        if (item.Contains(':'))
            result.Add(item);
        else
            result[^1] += result[^1][^1] == ':' ? " " + item : item;
    }

    return result.ToArray();
}


Такой парсер сломается при малейшем изменении текста на странице. Если используете AngleSharp, попробуйте CSS селекторами брать нужную ноду и из неё текст, а не просто текст всей страницы. В общем, есть решение гораздо лучше, чем этот цикл. HTML парсится как DOM (Document Object Model), а не как текст.

Достаточно одного цикла. Обрабатываете строки по очереди. Если в строке содержится ":" - запоминаете её индекс lastprop. Если в i-й строке снова встретили ":"  - объединяете строки от lastprop до i-1, записываете lastprop = i. Аналогично после цикла.
